# Should my PC go to sleep while robocopying?

Tags: robocopy

I noticed my PC goes to sleep while robocopying, so I' having to set the timer to a long time in Settings > Power&Sleep > Sleep.

I checked with the powercfg -requests command it it seems to confirm that nothing is preventing the PC from sleeping while copying.

This is the command I'm doing:
Robocopy D:\ E:\ /MIR  /R:0 /NP /SL /SJ /NFL /NDL /XF /XA:o /B /LOG:"C:\Users\Franz\Documents\Backup4.log

Is this the expected behaviour?

Windows 10 21H2

Comment: If your machine is going to sleep that means the copying is being suspended.  You should completely disable sleep on your machine while the job is running

Comment: If you have a low power PC (my PC uses 15 watts), set to never sleep when connected by AC and then set the monitor to turn the display off after 15 minutes. This uses minimal power and prevents issues.

Comment: I found bad sectors in the source disk and the average transfer speed was very very low (0.5MBps) then I replaced that disk for a similar 2TB HDD and the transfer rate was around 60MBps.  Maybe that halted the transfer at times?  I set /R:0 so it wasn't reattempting.   I didn't check if the sleeping happened with the new drive though, as I just disabled sleep for this last transfer.

 Thanks for your answers.